# detect expandiblelistview group when i click in imageview inside of this

Tags: android

I'm trying to expand a group of `ExpandableListView` when I click in an `ImageView` inside of this group.
I tried this:

```
  expLista.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            grupoCLickeado = groupPosition;
            ImageView btnExpandir = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgExpandir);
            // btnExpandir.setFocusable(false);
            btnExpandir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    LinearLayout parentRow = (LinearLayout) v.getParent()
                            .getParent();

                    expLista.expandGroup(grupoCLickeado);
                }
            });

            return true;
        }
    });
```

But this only works if every time that I want to collapse or expand the group, I click in an empty zone of the group.

I can't obtain the group ID otherwise, when I click in the `ImageView` inside a row it doesn't detect which group is the group of this `ImageView`.

How can I detect this?